# MIsunderstanding at php magic method __call()

Tags: php, oop

```
     class My_class {

        public function __call($name, $arguments) {

            echo "Called method ".$name.", arguments count is: ".count($arguments);

        }


    }

    $obj = new My_class();

    $arr = array(1,2,3);

    $obj->blabla($arr);
```

result is: `Called method blabla, arguments count is: 1`

Question: why arguments count is `1` and not `3`? where I am wrong?

Comment: Because you are passing single parameter - array. If you want three - call it using `$obj->blabla(1,2,3)`

Comment: @ J0HN Thanks, (but I need more characters for posting this)

Answer (score 0):

The script doesn't count the items in the array, only the argument number, and the only argument is $arr.

You need to count the items using:

```
count($arr);
```